# How to define an alias for a type in Python for type hinting

Tags: python, type-hinting, typing

How to define an alias for a type to use type hint:

```
import typing
type Ticker str # How to do this? I used golang notation. How do you do it in python?
Report = typing.Dict[Ticker, typing.List]
```

Which means Ticker is a type of string and Report is a dict from Ticker to a list. Thank you. 
The good thing about this aliasing is that anyone knows that it is a ticker. Much clear and more readable than writing Report = typing.Dict[str, typing.List]

Comment: There's no such type as "a string of five characters" in Python. Strings can be any length. So you can't do that.

Comment: OK. I changed it to make it just str. How do you define a new type Alias to str or any other type?

Comment: `Ticker = str`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you do with all other names that you bind to objects:

```
Ticker = typing.Text
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases