# How can I make sure two variables always have the same type-hints without explicitly giving them the same type?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I want something like this:

```py
a: some_type
b: same_type_as[a]

assert reveal_type(a) == reveal_type(b)
```

In practice these two variables are defined in very different places. I want to use the type-system to make sure they always have the same type. I want to avoid problems that arise, when a developer changes one variable, but forgets to update the other.

It should also work if one of the types is implicitly defined. For example

```py
def f() -> some_type:
    return something

a = f()
b: same_type_as[a]

assert reveal_type(a) == reveal_type(b)
```

Comment: How about declaring the type of both variables as a type alias? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693117/how-to-define-an-alias-for-a-type-in-python-for-type-hinting

Comment: that would work in general, but not in my case, because the type of `a` comes from the return value of another function.